# Matplotlib line won't show up

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a very simple graph in matplotlib, and for some reason it produces a graph without a line.

The plotting code:

```
    print(infected_list)
    print(generations_list)
    plt.plot([generations_list],[infected_list])
    plt.ylabel("Infected")
    plt.xlabel("Generations")
    plt.show()
```

I've also tried it with:

```
plt.plot([generations_list],[infected_list],color="red")
```

The output of the print function, showing the values of infected_list and generations_list:

```
[1, 2, 3.6, 6.8, 13.2, 26.0, 51.6, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100]
[0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

The resulting graph, with no line:
[image: Graph without line]

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Get rid of the extra `[]`. You're passing a list of a list.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Wow, I'm an idiot. That fixed it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It was a very simple mistake on my part, I was passing a list of a list. All I had to do was change

```
plt.plot([generations_list],[infected_list])
```

to

```
plt.plot(generations_list,infected_list)
```

Thank you to Mateen Ulhaq for answering it so quickly!